# Asterisk in bash script's variable value executed by jenkinsfile causes glob pattern

Tags: shell, glob

I've created a jenkins job that reads Cron schedule (string) param from the user and passes it forward to some a bash script that will insert the value into some yaml file:

```
stringParam(name: "CRON_SCHEDULE", description: "What is the Cron job schedule? (e.g. * * * * *) ")
```

These schedules usually contain asterisks - which causes the bash script to list the files in the current directory, instead of just act as a string (as the groovy file defined).

When I call the bash script from the groovy file and send over the (named) parameters:

`sh "./scripts/create_yaml.sh CRON_SCHEDULE=\"'$params.CRON_SCHEDULE'\" "`

The schedule seems fine (in the job's log):

+create_yaml.sh CRON_SCHEDULE='0 0 * * *'

But when the bash script is reading this parameter and also inserting it into yaml files it lists the files and the param comes out like this:

'0 0 file1 file2 file3 file1 file2 file3 file1 file2 file3'

I've tried every quotes manipulation I know of, outside the bash script and inside as well and I don't know what to try next.

How can I pass on and handle this parameter as a normal string?

Here is the bash script that receives the schedule param and creates the yaml:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ARGUMENT in "$@"
do

KEY=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f1 -d=)
VALUE=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f2 -d=)   

case "$KEY" in
        APPLICATION_NAME) 
            APPLICATION_NAME=${VALUE} ;;
        IMAGE_NAME)
            IMAGE_NAME=${VALUE} ;;
        APPLICATION_TYPE)
            APPLICATION_TYPE=${VALUE} ;;
        CRON_SCHEDULE)
                CRON_SCHEDULE="${VALUE}" ;;
        CHART_FOLDER)  
            CHART_FOLDER=${VALUE} ;;    
esac    
done

echo "cron schedule is ${CRON_SCHEDULE}";

touch ./$CHART_FOLDER/values.yaml

if [ $APPLICATION_TYPE == "cronjob" ]; then
cat > "./$CHART_FOLDER/values.yaml" << EOF
  image:  
   image: $IMAGE_NAME
    tag: base

cron:
  production:
    schedule: "$CRON_SCHEDULE"
EOF
fi
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: It's a shame you haven't posted a single line of code.

Comment: `create_yaml.sh` is using `$1` unquoted.

Comment: @glennjackman I couldn't give example of all the quote-settings I've tried so I just pasted it without any.. but thanks for the suggestion. I've edited the post in order to be more clear

Comment: We're telling you that thte problem is not in groovy but in the shell script.

Comment: @glennjackman I'm not using positional parameters, but named param. And inside the create_yaml script I tried several ways of receiving its value - including quotes and apostrophes..   but didn't fully manage to resolve the listing-asterisk issue.

Comment: Then show us the whole `create_yaml` script. We can't properly debug code you don't show. "Lets not make things worse by guessing" (Gene Kranz, Apollo 13 Mission Control).

Comment: That's where the problem is, so put that code in your question.

Comment: @Jens Updated.
As you can see I receive this param with double quotes. Is there a way I should receive it that will keep it as a whole string?  and not glob pattern?

Comment: @EladTalby, nothing about `groovy` in your question. please remove this tag.

Comment: Could you add `args=("$@"); declare -p args` on top of the script and post it's output?

Comment: @KamilCuk Sure. This is the output
declare -a args=([0]="APPLICATION_NAME=Testing1" [1]="APPLICATION_DESCRIPTION=testRun" [2]="IMAGE_NAME=imageName" [3]="SENTRY_DSN=DSN" [4]="COMMAND=command" [5]="COMMAND_ARGS=args" [6]="APPLICATION_TYPE=cronjob" [7]="EXPOSE_JIRA=false" [8]="EXPOSE_WORKATO=false" [9]="CRON_SCHEDULE='0 0 0 * *'" [10]="CHART_FOLDER=chart_output")

Comment: `9]="CRON_SCHEDULE='0 0 0 * *'` has spaces in it. Write a parser   it. Check your script with shellcheck.net - quote all expansions. Use indentation to make code readable. Do not use upper case variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=([0]="APPLICATION_NAME=Testing1" [1]="APPLICATION_DESCRIPTION=testRun" [2]="IMAGE_NAME=imageName" [3]="SENTRY_DSN=DSN" [4]="COMMAND=command" [5]="COMMAND_ARGS=args" [6]="APPLICATION_TYPE=cronjob" [7]="EXPOSE_JIRA=false" [8]="EXPOSE_WORKATO=false" [9]="CRON_SCHEDULE='0 0 0 * *'" [10]="CHART_FOLDER=chart_output")
set -- "${args[@]}"

for i in "$@"; do
    IFS== read -r key value <<<"$i"
    # remove single quotes
    if [[ "$value" =~ ^\'(.*)\'$ ]]; then
        value=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    fi
    # use declare to declare the variable with that value
    declare "$key=$value"
done

echo "cron schedule is ${CRON_SCHEDULE}";

cat << EOF
  image:  
   image: $IMAGE_NAME
    tag: base

cron:
  production:
    schedule: "$CRON_SCHEDULE"
EOF
```

outputs:

```
cron schedule is 0 0 0 * *
  image:  
   image: imageName
    tag: base

cron:
  production:
    schedule: "0 0 0 * *"
```